# javascript - run chrome extension as soon as page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wan't to run my chrome extension as soon as the web page the user is visiting completes loading.

The extension works fine if I click it but I want it to run automatically on page load.

Is there any way to do this?

Here is my manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Simple Text Highlighter",
    "description": "This plugin notify of the word 'Simple' in the current page",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "highlightSimple.js"],
        "css": ["highlight.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ]

}
```

and here is the JavaScript

```
(function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'highlight.css'
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'jquery.min.js'
        }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: 'replace.js'
            });
        });
    })
})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `run_at` field `document_end`, which means your scripts will be injected as soon as the page loads.

> the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.

And `chrome.tabs.executeScript` can only be called in extension context, it's not allowed in content scripts.